# Angular 8 Ngx-image-cropper is not an angular module - import error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement ngx-image-cropper. I made a component in which the image cropper will be used, and added the import to the imports section like this:

```
import { ImageCropperModule } from 'ngx-image-cropper';

@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
ImageCropperModule
],
```

But I'm getting

> Class ImageCropperModule is not an Angular module

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: which version of angular you are working on ?

Comment: I installed this `1.3.10` and it worked for me `npm install ngx-image-cropper@1.3.10 --save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ImageCropperModule } from 'ngx-image-cropper';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';



@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ImageCropperModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageCroppedEvent } from 'ngx-image-cropper';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  imageChangedEvent: any = '';
  croppedImage: any = '';

  fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
      this.imageChangedEvent = event;
  }
  imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
      this.croppedImage = event.base64;
  }
  imageLoaded() {
      // show cropper
  }
  cropperReady() {
      // cropper ready
  }
  loadImageFailed() {
      // show message
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />

<image-cropper
    [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
    [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
    [aspectRatio]="4 / 3"
    format="png"
    (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
    (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
    (cropperReady)="cropperReady()"
    (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
></image-cropper>

<img [src]="croppedImage" />
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-image-cropper)